# Looping Footage Pauses On Last Keyframe Before Executing gotoAndPlay("loop");

Tags: flash, loops, actionscript

Using Flash Professsional CS5 with Actionscript: I have a 6 second movie I need to continuously loop from the half-way point out, after it plays through once.

I've used the gotoAndPlay("loop"); script to loop it. But here is a distinct pause on the last keyframe before it loops each time, which destroys the essential flow of the animation.

It can be viewed here: http://vivalasvacations.com/108/W2U/W2UComp06(LOOPED).swf

The globe pauses after one revolution before it repeats.

Does anybody have any suggestions as to how I might rid this project of the dreaded pause? Perhaps another method of looping is available which would render things more smoothly?

Thanks,
Steve

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be any noticeable pause when you loop. My guess is that it's due to repeated frames. Try the following:

1. Check that the first and final frames of the spinning globe animation are not the same
2. Check that there are no repeated frames at the start and end of the animation

**Update:**

I see from your profile, that you've asked much the same question two times previously and received very similar responses to mine in both cases. My suggestion would be that you upload the file somewhere and put links to it in your post and in a comment under my answer. If you do that, I'll have a look and see if I can figure out what the problem is.

**Update II:**

I think the issue might be because your animation is `FLV` based. I would suggest re-encoding the file with a key-frame for each frame of the video (there should be a setting somewhere in your encoding software to allow this), this will increase the file-size but should mean it loops smoothly.

Comment: http://vivalasvacations.com/108/W2U/W2UComp06(LOOPED).swf

I have tested this bug in every conceivable way, including in simple loop projects with no other layers in them. It seems that this is a bug in Flash itself, as I've seen/tried 3 distinctly different methods for looping and each produces a pause on the last frame of the looped footage.

I'm thinking trying even more creative ways of looping footage in Flash to find a workaround and achieve a truly seamless loop may be the way to go at this point.

Comment: Oops... sorry, here's a link to the .FLA file:

http://vivalasvacations.com/108/W2U/W2UComp06(LOOPED).fla